# Retrieving Text From Website

Tags: coronasdk

Is there any way to retrieve the text from a website such as a Wikipiedia site using Corona SDK **without** having to parse through all of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MediaWiki api doc](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) to get data from wikipedia. Just don't forget to use the format as json.

Comment: Very interesting, I will check this out and if I find it works, I will definitely choose you as the solution! Thanks a lot!